# Disco dingo - mysql workbench - issue in installing

Tags: mysql

Disco dingo - mysql workbench - issue in installing

Getting following:

```
prashant@prashant-ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install mysql-workbench
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package mysql-workbench is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'mysql-workbench' has no installation candidate
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now, mysql workbench is available for ubuntu 19.04. You can manually install after downloading the file.

Step 1: Direct download link- https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/file/?id=488567

OR

Visit here select your OS then download as per OS version https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/

Step 2: sudo apt install file_path_of_downloaded_workbench

for me it is:

```
sudo apt install /home/prashant/customInstallations/mysql-workbench-community_8.0.17-1ubuntu19.04_amd64.deb
```

Finish!!